# Use of public and final

Tags: java

I recently wrote code like this:

```
class Test{
  public int a;
  public int b;
  public void demo(){
    //public int c;
    final int d;
  }
}
```

Commented code can not be compiled. I always thought that the argument can be `public`，like `b`, but why not `c`?

Answer (score 4):

`public int c` is an error since local variables are only visible to the method in which they are declared, so there's no meaning to access modifiers.

As for `final int b`, I didn't notice you are assigning 0 to it. It should be fine. The problem may have been that you had two variables named `b` (assuming the commented line doesn't replace the uncommented `b` declaration).

Comment: @Shonminh i hardly doubt that `final int b=0` wont compile since it has the right syntax. maybe there is some other mistake in there

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I must be seeing things (or no seeing things). Fixed now.

Comment: @ Kevin Esche I find i have redefined `b` , corrected it now .Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Visibility modifiers like `public` describe if some element or type can be accessed from other type. They can be applied to

- type (class, interface, enums)
- and top level elements of types like

  - fields,
  - methods,
  - constructors,
  - inner-types.

Using access modifier with local variables like `c` doesn't make sense since local variables *can be seen* only in local scope (in `{...}` scope they ware declared - in your case inside `demo` method), so you can't limit nor increase that visibility range.

Answer (score 1):

In combination with variables public shows the acceslevel to this specific variable in a class. [SO about public-private-protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

You are trying to define a variable public inside a method, this will throw an error, since this variable is only locally accessible inside this method and therefore the wouldn´t have any usefull meaning.

The other error is generated due to a missing decleration of the class variable, which is needed when using the keyword final.

Answer (score 1):

Only class variable can have access modifiers like private or public. So you cannot have final variable inside demo() method.

For final int b=0, you have already defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Here one of four fundamental concept of OOP come in role it is Encapsulation.

Encapsulation is the technique of making the fields in a class private and providing access to the fields via public methods. If a field is declared private, it cannot be accessed by anyone outside the class, thereby hiding the fields within the scop of it

Encapsulation can be described as a protective barrier that prevents the code and data being randomly accessed by other code defined outside the class.

In case of your code you said, argument can be public，like b but why not c. It is because scope the c is only for method demo() and it will accessible only within it. Same is applicable for final.

Comment: I think most of you said is right, but the `final`  can be declared inside the method.

Comment: Yes you can declare final as other field and same is applicable for it except there will only one copy of final no matter how many object is created.